# How do you show only one of 2 outcomes using table1 in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

The following code produces a table that tells us a number of things, in particular how many of the cars were Chevy (split by Sound).

```
library(caret)
data(cars)
library(table1)
table1( ~factor(Chevy) + Mileage |Sound, data =cars )
```

The table outputs how many cars were Chevy (Chevy[i] = 1) and how many weren't (Chevy[i]=0). I'd like to display only one of these two in the table, say (Chevy[i] = 1), so as to not have redundant clutter. Can I do this with table1? How do I output the same table that the above code produces without the Chevy = 0 row?

Edit: I originally forgot to load caret, which is where the cars dataset is located.

Comment: I think you're missing something here. There is no data with Chevy, Mileage (though there is a `dist` column), or Sound. It would be easier to just provide the data via `dput`. You can even just provide a little with `dput(head(df))`.

Comment: Maybe you can add some data to begin the problem.  ``cars`` data do not have a Chevy factor, did you create that variable? If so can you add some parts of the dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on the Github for table1. https://github.com/benjaminrich/table1/issues/48

This is an exact quote of the code that was written there. It is not my own.

```
library(boot) 

melanoma$status <- 
  factor(melanoma$status, 
         levels=c(2,1,3),
         labels=c("Alive", # Reference
                  "Melanoma death", 
                  "Non-melanoma death"))

melanoma$ulcer <- as.logical(melanoma$ulcer)

label(melanoma$ulcer) <- "Ulceration Present &mdash; no. (%)"
label(melanoma$age)   <- "Age (years)"

rndr <- function(x, ...) {
    y <- render.default(x, ...)
    if (is.logical(x)) y[2] else y
}

table1(~ ulcer + age | status, data=melanoma, render=rndr)
```